# Installing Synergy on Mac OS X Verison 10.6.7, I having issue understanding the steps 3 and 4

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, synergy

I'm having issue understanding the steps 3 and 4

Listen below I'm trying to get this to work on my MacBook

## Mac OS X Readme

To install on Mac OS X with the .zip distribution (first seen in 1.3.6) you must follow these steps:

1. Extract the zip file to any location (usually double click will do this)
2. Open Terminal, and cd to the extracted directory (e.g. /Users/my-name/Downloads/extracted-dir/)
3. Change to super user (use the su command)
4. Copy the binaries to /usr/bin using: cp synergy* /usr/bin

How to enable the root user in Mac OS X:

Once the binaries have been copied to /usr/bin, you should follow the configuration guide:

If you have any problems, see the [[Support]] page:

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully completed Step 2, then `Terminal` is still open. You can complete Steps 3 and 4 simultaneously by typing:

> `sudo cp synergy* /usr/bin`

What this command does is copy the Synergy files to the correct location (`cp ...`) but does it with elevated permissions (`sudo`).

Comment: Once copy it takes me back to this prompt is that correct

Comment: Once copy it takes me back to this prompt is that correct unknown002608e3b2de:synergy-1-1 robertrujr$

Comment: How do you run synergy on the mac it's no application in the application folder for synergy

Comment: Correct, it isn't, it's in /usr/bin instead. That suggests that Synergy is a command-line tool. Synergy has some decent documentation: http://synergy-foss.org/pm/projects/synergy/wiki/UsingSynergy

Answer (score 1):

The command #3 has you become the "super user" on your system, a user who can every everything potentially.

Read the Apple technical note about this:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528

The command #4 is a copy command.

1. First extract the zip file you downloaded. Mine ended up in my Downloads directory.
2. Open a terminal. In OSX 10.6, to Applications, Utilities, Terminal.
3. Change directory to you Downloads directory:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/synergy-1.4....
   ```
4. Now you can run the #4 command from the read me!

   This will copy the two programs in your /usr/bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out SynergyKM (http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergykm/) a GUI for Synergy on the Mac. I've been using it in my PC/Mac Synergy setup for a couple weeks now and it made setup much easier.

Synergy itself has no native GUI so you'll need to launch it from the command line otherwise. There are detailed documents on both using the command line at synergy-foss.org on the Docs page in the End Users section.